# How to correct name weight not define error

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am learning python by printing the output line by line from this tutorial https://towardsdatascience.com/convolution-neural-network-for-image-processing-using-keras-dc3429056306 and find out what does each line do. At the last line of code I facing error weight not define but it seem the code is running fine without the need to define the weight as inside the tutorial link. What I did wrongly in the code and how to fix it?

```
 import numpy as np
 import torch
 import torch.nn as nn
 import torch.nn.functional as fn
 filter_vals = np.array([[-1, -1, 1, 2], [-1, -1, 1, 0], [-1, -1, 1, 1], [-1, -1, 1, 
 1]])
 print('Filter shape: ', filter_vals.shape)# Neural network with one convolutional layer 
 and four filters

 # Neural network with one convolutional layer and four filters
 class Net(nn.Module):
 def __init__(self, weight): super(Net, self).__init__()
 k_height, k_width = weight.shape[2:]
```

Comment: You are learning python by **starting with convolutional neural networks**?

Comment: Yes, I'm learning Image processing and programming at the same time as part of my school project which is a challenging module as having a steep learning curve, have to deal with things I'm entirely not familiar with.

Comment: In machine learning, the **steeper** curve is the curve where the model learned faster. So a steep learning curve actually corresponds to a quickly learned task. Are you sure that deep learning is what you need for a school project, and not something simpler such as the OpenCV library?

Comment: I'm in my degree final year doing final year project. Not really dealing much with programming in the past. I purposely picked a title using image processing to count people as I think it will benefit me more in long run. I already know how to use tensor flow zoo model API to perform the task. Still have several months to go before project submission, currently just taking time hoping to learn something deeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to an indentation issue. The last line needs to be executed inside the constructor **init** for it to recognize the weight argument. The code should look like this:

```
 import numpy as np
 import torch
 import torch.nn as nn
 import torch.nn.functional as fn
 
 filter_vals = np.array([[-1, -1, 1, 2], 
                         [-1, -1, 1, 0], 
                         [-1, -1, 1, 1], 
                         [-1, -1, 1, 1]])

 print('Filter shape: ', filter_vals.shape) # Neural network with one convolutional layer and four filters

 # Neural network with one convolutional layer and four filters
 class Net(nn.Module):
     def __init__(self, weight): 
         super(Net, self).__init__()
         k_height, k_width = weight.shape[2:]
```